# How do i attach fragments using on options item selected using menu items

Tags: android, android-fragments, menuitem

Hello am having a menu layout that has a menu item. The menu item has an item with action view class which is supposed to attach a fragment on click. How do i get to attach the AccountManagementFragment when use clicks on the action_account menu item using action view class of the menu item

My menu item layout

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_account"
        android:title="Account"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        app:actionViewClass="ke.co.clinton.hama.viewslogic.account.AccountManagementFragment"/>
```

My onCreateOptionsMenu and onOptionsItemsSelected methods

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.search) {

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
```

My fragment class

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import ke.co.clinton.hama.MainActivity;
import ke.co.clinton.hama.R;
import ke.co.clinton.hama.interfaces.DrawerLocker;

public class AccountManagementFragment extends Fragment {

    private AccountManagementViewModel mViewModel;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
        ((DrawerLocker) getActivity()).setDrawerEnabled(false);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account_management, container, false);
        Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Title");
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_back_button);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getActivity().onBackPressed();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(AccountManagementViewModel.class);
        // TODO: Use the ViewModel

    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
        ((DrawerLocker) getActivity()).setDrawerEnabled(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
        ((DrawerLocker) getActivity()).setDrawerEnabled(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass `Fragment` as `app:actionViewClass` in menu items. What you can really do is attach the fragment when the menu item is selected inside `onOptionItemSelected`.

1. Remove the `app:actionViewClass` from menu item

   ```
   <item android:id="@+id/action_account"
       android:title="Account"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile"
       app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"/>
   ```
2. Add a static method inside `AccountManagementFragment` to get the instance

   ```
   public class AccountManagementFragment extends Fragment {
       ...
       ...

       static AccountManagementFragment newInstance() {
           return AccountManagementFragment();
       }
       ...
       ...
   }
   ```
3. Change the implementation of `onOptionsItemSelected` to add the fragment

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

       if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_account) {
           // Make sure to add a fragment container view in the layout (preferably a FrameLayout)
           // Here I am assuming the id is 'container'
           getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
               .replace(R.id.container, AccountManagementFragment.newInstance())
               .commit()
       }

       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
   ```